# Getter unexpectedly called a second time for inout parameter

Tags: swift, swift2

I'm learning Swift and I cannot understand why this code printed out a redundant output:

```
class A {}
var x: A {
    set { print("set") }
    get {
        print("get")
        return A()
    }
}
func f(inout y: A) { print("f") }
f(&x)
```

The result is:

```
get
f
set
get
```

Why the last get here?
If I add another inout parameter in f:

```
class A {}
var x: A {
    set { print("set") }
    get {
        print("get")
        return A()
    }
}
func f(inout y: A, inout z: Int) { print("f") }
var z = 10
f(&x, z:&z)
```

The new result is:

```
get
f
set
```

Can you clear me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am guessing you are writing this code in the playground!?

If you put it into a regular project and run it on the simulator, you will not see that behavior.
**It only occurs in the playground**.

On the device both methods print the expected

> get
> f
> set

---

## Explanation:

The playground execution looks like this:

[image]

Notice the `A` in the last line printed on the right side? The Playground tries to display the value of the `x` and for it to display it, it accesses its getter! If you have multiple parameters Xcode does not attempt to print anything -> adding a second parameter causes Xcode to not `get` any value.

Comment: I added no inout parameter. The result is same as first. If I add a inout parameter. The result will different. Anyway, thanks for your point. I think you are correct. I will verify this late.

Comment: @aviit What do you mean?

Comment: I mean I have just started with Swift in Playground only :) . I have not yet learned to code in others. Thanks!

Comment: @aviit Did you have time to verify that my answer is correct?

Comment: Thanks, I will verify then mark your answer as solved. I'm reading the book and I just try in the Playground now.